# Console o/p taking too long with subprocess.popen

Tags: python

I want to import data into Oracle db using impdb tool and this command should run from python process. Below is the code snippet of py.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(''impdp mssumm/mssumm@Oracle_Instance DUMPFILE=_SUMMARYDB_DIRECT_EXPORT_SOL_20150312_1123_DATAPUMPMSSUMM.DMP', bufsize=1, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        for line in p.stderr:
            if'IMP-00010:' in line:
                print('Custom message')
                sys.exit(1)
            print(str(line.rstrip()))
            p.stderr.flush()
```

Here i want to display the o/p to console continuously and at the same time, have to check for errors (eg: IMP-00010) and based on the error code i have to continue the import or exit.

But this piece of code taking significantly long time to display the o/p. I want to continuously display the o/p like each line and at the same time compare that with error code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have two single quote characters at the start of your command, or is that a copy and paste issue?  You should not need to convert `line` to a string to print it, it is already a string (otherwise `rstrip` wouldn't work), and print "stringifies" for you.  You should not need to flush stderr since it is unbuffered (unless you changed it elsewhere).   I would not expect a significant performance issue with any of those however.  Bear in mind that stdout is buffered, and you are doing nothing with that, so stderr and stdout might not be synchronised.

Comment: I just have one single quote, that's just a typo. I'll try your suggested changes. Can you just clarify me how can i avoid stderr and stdout synchronisation issue, Also what happens if i change the buffer size to some number like 1024.

Comment: It is still taking time to display the o/p. May be it is waiting to complete the whole import and then it is displaying. I just want to avoid this delay of displaying each line.

Comment: Increasing the buffer size might delay the output being displayed, since it will be written to the buffer and not to the screen, however it is program dependant and many systems flush after a newline.  `bufsize=1` is strange: a flush after each character is unusual and probably inefficient, what was your reason for that?  `bufsize=0` might be appropriate.  You could use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to display it yourself, but that will be more work.

Comment: I've tried with bufsize=0, but no luck. The output is not continuous.It is waiting till the process ends and finally it is displaying all the o/p at one shot. This is not my expected behavior. I need to get the each line of o/p from subprocess and then validate and display.